# Why can't I use == with generics even when IEquatable<T> is specified?

Tags: c#

I want to write custom array class. So I define it like this:

```
public class AmazingArray<T> where T: System.IEquatable<T> {...}
```

I explicitly tell that `T` should have `Equals` method which works with `T`. But when I try to compare them, like in this example:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < effectiveSize; ++i)
            {
                if (storage[i] == item)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I get a build error stating I can't compare `T` and `T`:

```
  AmazingArray.cs(75, 21): [CS0019] Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Why can't I compare them, even though generic type must have `Equals`, since it is stated in `where` statement?

Comment: You compare objects for equality by using `Equals()`, not `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Equals` and `==` are *completely different things*, that can have completely different meanings and implementations, and which have no hard association. You can use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y)`, though - this respects `IEquatable<T>` in a way that works correctly (and efficiently) with all scenarios including nulls, structs, nullable-structs, etc.